# WiFi speed is 10 times slower on my PC then on my phone

Tags: wifi

I am new to elementary, having installed it today (without clicking the update or install drivers in installation) and I noticed the abysmal internet speeds on my computer. Tested it using fast.com and got 3 Mbps on my phone and 0.3 Mbps on my computer.

I am guessing its some kind of driver error since I did not install any WiFi drivers yet but I also found no guides on this matter (running a built in Intel ® Dual Band Wireless-AC 9260).

So if it is a missing driver, how do I install it? and if not what is the issue?

Comment: I recommend you to connect the phone to your computer through USB cable, set USB-tethering on your phone in order to shre internet from your phone to your computer without wi-fi(but through the usb cable) and do the same tests. Edit your question with the results - does it change, or again you have a lot more slower internet on your computer?

Comment: I tried that and it showed good internet, solved it awns: the antenna was folded in, Bluetooth was on and the wireless mouse antenna was placed on a USB port next to the WIFI antennas so they completely handicapped the card. Solved all three and speeds are back to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a hardware issue:

- USB antenna was next to the WiFi antennas
- WiFi antennas themselves were folded in too much
- Bluetooth was on